# Why are my variables not updating in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, embedded-javascript

I have built a webapp with node.js to receive messages from an SNS topic via POST request and log them to the console then display them on the webpage, if I publish a message to my topic I get the message printed in the console but nothing updates on my webpage?

This is my code for `app.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require('request')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs")


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  let subject = "Your Subject Will Appear Here";
  let message = "Your Message Will Appear Here";
  res.render("index", {subject:subject, message:message});
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let body = ''
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk.toString()
  })  
  req.on('end', () => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(body)
    if (payload.Type === 'Notification') {
      console.log(payload.Message);
      let subject = payload.Subject;
      let message = payload.Message;
      res.render("index", {subject:subject, message:message});
    }
  });
});

app.listen(80, process.env.IP, function(request, response){
    console.log("## SERVER STARTED ##");
});
```

This is my code for `index.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <% if(subject !== null){ %>
            <p>SNS Subject: <%= subject %></p>
          <% } %>
        <% if(message !== null){ %>
            <p>SNS Message: <%= message %></p>
          <% } %>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your variables are **local** variables within the `get` and `post` callback functions. If you want them to persist outside the scope of those callbacks, you need to move them to a scope that won't go away when the callback returns.

For instance, this makes them module globals **BUT** it seems like it would be odd for every POST, regardless of who it came from, to change the content of unrelated GETs (see `***` comments):

```
// *** Declared at module scope
let subject = "Your Subject Will Appear Here";
let message = "Your Message Will Appear Here";

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // *** Not declared here
  res.render("index", {subject:subject, message:message});
})

// ...

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let body = ''
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk.toString()
  })  
  req.on('end', () => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(body)
    if (payload.Type === 'Notification') {
      console.log(payload.Message);
      subject = payload.Subject; // <======= *** no `let`, we're not declaring here
      message = payload.Message; // <======= *** same
      res.render("index", {subject:subject, message:message});
    }
  });
});
```

But again, that probably wouldn't make sense. You'll probably need some kind of per-user or per-session storage mechanism (such as a database, or expiring in-memory cache, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense I've only recently started using nodejs coming from Python, I wasn't even thinking about scope!